# jQuery addClass to next ul

Tags: jquery

how would I go about adding a class to the next ul.

```
$("#main-navigation a:contains('About')").after("<span id=mabout></span>");
$("#mabout").closest('ul').addClass('moveme');


There are more list elements before and after...

<li ><a href="">About</a>

<a class='menu-icon plus' href='#'><img src=''/></a>

<ul> <<-- ONLY THIS

    <li ><a href="">Lower</a>

<a class='menu-icon plus' href='#'><img src=''/></a>

<ul>
```

So I'm only looking to add a class to the very next UL, Thanks.

Comment: Please post that HTML properly and a bit more, so that others can understand your question properly.

Comment: The HTML is generated dynamically, the poor markup isn't something I can help sorry.

Comment: so basically you want to add a class in each ul under an li ?

Comment: Just the one ul, the next one.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$('li > ul').addClass('moveme');
```

You can also target next `ul` as below code,

```
$('li ul:first').addClass('moveme');
```

**OR**

```
$('li').find('ul:first').addClass('moveme');
```

Comment: There are many more list elements. Would that not only effect one?

Comment: There are LI's before, I'm looking to be specific for the first after the span.

Comment: It's the same all the way through except the titles (e.g About).

Answer (score 1):

The first step would be to clean up the markup, there are several missing end tags:

```
<li id="mabout">
    <a href="">About</a>
    <a class='menu-icon plus' href='#'><img src=''/></a>
</li>
<ul> <<-- ONLY THIS
    <li >
        <a href="">Lower</a>
        <a class='menu-icon plus' href='#'><img src=''/></a>
    </li>
<ul>
```

Notice in the markup the first `li` was given the id, `mabout`, which was missing.  This should allow the following script to work:

```
$("#mabout").next('ul').addClass('moveme');
```

**Js Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/g3KYW/

Comment: The list is dynamically generated, hens why I had to add a span myself.

Comment: You are assuming that the id="About" is there.

Comment: @Alex yes I am. I added it to the markup. Do you not have this option?

Comment: No, the HTML is dynamically generated.

Comment: Yikes, what is generating it?  Its producing some nasty markup.

Comment: I know lol it's from WordPress, thought it would be easy to just add a class, since I only need the edit for one of the items.